# Puppet pre-generated certificates for multiple agents

Tags: puppet

I have a requirement like below

1. I have generated pre-generated certificates in master for multiple agents with some name
2. I have to copy the pre-generated certificate to all the agents.
3. All the clients which have pre-generated certificate, should be able to pull the catalog from master.

Please help me on this.

I have tried, but I am getting an error like below
           Error: Could not request certificate: The certificate retrieved from the master does not match the agent's private key.
           Certificate fingerprint:

With Regards,
Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out?  What exactly did you transfer to your clients?  If you pre-generatge the keys/certs on the master/ca, then you must transfer the private key and the certificate to the clients.  The way your question is worded makes me suspect that you have only transferred the certificates you generated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what steps you took. But here is a working example -- for a multi-VM vagrant setup I use this snippet to install different puppet certificates depending on hostname:

```
HOST=`hostname -s`
echo "Hello World from $0 on $HOST. Now installing puppet ssl keys ..."

mkdir -p /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys /var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys
chown puppet:puppet /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys /var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys

if [[ -e "/home/vagrant/files/vagrant_keys/${HOST}.vm.example.org.pem_cert" ]]; then
    cp /home/vagrant/files/vagrant_keys/${HOST}.vm.example.org.pem_cert    /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/${HOST}.vm.example.org.pem
    cp /home/vagrant/files/vagrant_keys/${HOST}.vm.example.org.pem_private /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/${HOST}.vm.example.org.pem
    cp /home/vagrant/files/vagrant_keys/${HOST}.vm.example.org.pem_public  /var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys/${HOST}.vm.example.org.pem
else
    echo "no puppet ssl certificate found for ${HOST}.vm.example.org"
    echo "please sign and deploy the new one, generated in /var/lib/puppet/ssl"
fi
```